# How to implement refresh token in django-oauth-toolkit? I'm able to get access_token but the refresh token isn't coming with it

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-oauth-toolkit, oauth-refresh-token

I'm using django-oauth-toolkit with djangorestframework where our partner user will register their application and get application credentials (client id and client secret) which then used to get access token that can be used further to get our server resources. Upto now I'm able to convert those form based application registration process and other apis through rest. But while I hit for access_token only access token with expire are coming as response. Refresh token also supposed to come along the access token but it's not. What I'm missing here...

Below is the sample api response for access_token
[image]

And the oauth2 settings
[image]

FYI: I'm using Client type as "Confidential" and Authorization grant type as "Client Credentials"

**Findings: This may be helpful for others**

There is no need for refresh token for grant type client credentials.

Further descriptions [RFC doc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.2.1) ; [grant type client credentials](https://documentation.softwareag.com/webmethods/microservices_container/msc10-5/10-5_MSC_PIE_webhelp/index.html#page/integration-server-integrated-webhelp/to-configure_oauth_13.html)